# css issue with line spacing between text with there is more than two lines, ie7

Tags: html, css, joomla

In compatibility mode for ie7, I am noticing a weird spacing issue for internet explorer 7.  I have a joomla news feed arranged as links within a series of vertical list items.  For some reason, the white space height between each line of text seems to be variable.  Here is the url of the page in question, www.galloplaw.com.  What could I do or set to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't give any padding or margin to ul, li in every browser it takes some default margin and padding.

And the amount is different in different browsers.

So you need to do one thing, i.e **reset the margin and padding**.

Either use

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

to reset the margin of every element in the page or use

```
ul, li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

to reset the margin of ul and li element only.

After resetting it you can give your custom margin and padding.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using a true CSS reset like [Eric Meyer's reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [Normalize CSS](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/), but it maybe a little bit late in your project for that.

The problem here may be that, on your news li tags, you have top *and* bottom margins. In recent browsers, the bottom margin of one li will merge with the top margin of the following li. Not in IE7. You could remove the top margin from your li by deleting the following on line 475 of your css :

```
.latestnews li {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```